# how to make a recursive function asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, recursion

in my app  I need to calculate the offsetLeft of an absolute positioned element   ,but the problem is that its deeply nested so when  do `element.current.offsetLeft`  I get offsetLeft relative to the first parent that is positioned relative , I solved that by creating a  recursive function . the problem is that it takes some time finish because  it has to keep recalling it self until it reaches the body tag . so I'm hopping someone can help me modify my recursive function to be asynchronous .

this the component in which I'm using the functions

```
import React,{useRef}  from 'react'
import {getOffsetLeftRecursive} from '../../../utils/getOffsetLeftRecursive'

const ComponentA= ({todoList,index}) => {
    const elementRef= useRef()

    const clickStart=e=>{
        try {
            const res = await getOffsetLeftRecursive(elementRef.current,0)
            console.log(res)// this return undifned 
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
   
    return (
        <div 
        ref={elementRef}
        onMouseDown={clickStart} 
        className="shadow-xl"
        style={{
             left:(LIST_WIDTH +SPACING)*index
        }}
        className="absolute top-0 " > 
  
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodosList
```

and this is the recursive function

```
export const  getOffsetLeftRecursive= (element,accumulated)=>{
    try {
        if(element.tagName =="BODY"){
          console.log(accumulatedOffsetLeft) // this returns the correct value 
          return accumulatedWidth  
        }
        const offsetLeft =accumulatedWidth+ element.offsetLeft
        getOffsetLeftRecursive(element.parentElement,offsetLeft)
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: A `getOffsetLeft` function doesn't need to be asynchronous since none of the attribute accesses to get the offset rectangle for an element need to be asynchronous.

Comment: _"the problem is that it takes some time finish because it has to keep recalling it self until it reaches the body tag"_ - Even with hundreds of parents this shouldn't take more than some milliseconds.

Comment: I know it shouldn't take much time but still when I log the result I get undefined which is weird , have you looked at the code ?

Comment: You get `undefined` because you don't `return` when you recurse.

Comment: @سعيد - The `undefined` is because you don't return the result of the recursive call (missing `return` prior to it). But marking a function `async` that doesn't use `await` does nothing useful.

Comment: ah I get it ,  so I was getting the return for the first function call which is undefined obviously . thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `getOffsetLeft` function doesn't need to be asynchronous since none of the attribute accesses to get the offset rectangle for an element need to be asynchronous.

You're probably looking for something like

```
function getCumulativeOffsetLeft(element) {
  let offsetLeft = 0;
  while (element && element.tagName !== "BODY") {
    offsetLeft += element.offsetLeft;
    element = element.parentElement;
  }
  return offsetLeft;
}
```

which does the "recursion" (upward tree traversal) internally.

Comment: wow I can't believe I haven't thought of using a while loop which much more intuitive approach ,  very clean and simple

Comment: @سعيد "intuitive" is in the eye of the beholder. A [recursive solution](https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/b0e7b6b6c0268dafb3b3930cd02028c0) is pretty intuitive imo.

Comment: Agreeing with @3limin4t0r. See my answer in this thread for more :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion for this but there's not need for it to be asynchronous -

```js
const recursiveOffsetLeft = elem =>
  !elem || elem.tagName == "BODY"
    ? 0
    : Number(elem.offsetLeft) + recursiveOffsetLeft(elem.parentElement)
```

It's plenty safe as the element can be nested thousands of levels deep before it would cause a stack overflow.

One improvement I can see here is allowing the caller to specify the stopping point -

```js
const recursiveOffsetLeft = (elem, rel = document.body) =>
  !elem || elem === rel
    ? 0
    : Number(elem.offsetLeft) + recursiveOffsetLeft(elem.parentElement, rel)
```

This allows caller to reuse this function to calculate offsets of various depth -

```js
recursiveOffsetLeft(someElem) // defaults to document.body
recursiveOffsetLeft(someElem, someParent) // <-
```